# Is there a difference between Qiyamah and Akhirah?

Tags: judgements

What is Yaumul Qiyamah mentioned in 2:85? Why is it also mentioned in the same verse the term Akhirah?

Comment: Where is 'akhirah' mentioned in that ayah?

Answer (score 7):

*Qiyamah* (lit. standing) refers to the Day of Judgment; more specifically it refers to the standing that all humans will be doing on that day. Some will have it comfortable and it will seem like a breeze, and to others it will be a painful torment.

*Akhirah* refers in general to the world of the Hereafter, which begins with the Day of Judgment.

Answer (score 0):

**Qiyamah** - from verb QAMA (to Stand/Resurrect ) in context The hereafter emphasizing the **RESURRECTION**.

**Akhera** - from noun Akher (The Last/ The End) and in context The Hereafter **more general** encompassing Resurrection, Judgment, and punishment or reward.